How Does a Particle "Know" About Surface Curvature During a Collision?
I am exploring the dynamics of a particle colliding with a cylindrical surface at an angle θ. A particularly intriguing aspect of this scenario is how the particle "knows" about the surface curvature during the collision. This raises fundamental questions about the nature of the interaction.
When a particle approaches a cylindrical surface, it impacts at a specific angle, resulting in a deflection rather than a simple reversal of direction. This behavior suggests that the particle interacts with the curvature of the surface in a way that is not merely a random event. Instead, the angle of impact and the resulting motion appear to depend on the geometric properties of the cylinder.
From a microscopic perspective, the collision occurs at the atomic or molecular level, where forces between the particle and the surface come into play. However, I wonder how this microscopic interaction translates to a discernible response to the curvature of the surface. Is the particle's deflection purely a consequence of momentum and energy conservation, or is there a more fundamental principle at work?
Additionally, I would like to understand whether this curvature interaction is purely a microscopic phenomenon or if macroscopic properties, like the shape of the surface, significantly influence the collision outcomes. Are there specific theoretical models or frameworks that can explain how particles respond to curved surfaces?

basically, curvature - which means second derivative of the surface - does not matter here, only the first derivative, which determines the normal vector at the point of impact

How small is the particle compared to the atomic scale?  If large compared to atoms, but small compared to Cylinder, you get one result.  If it is small compared to atomic scale (or even scale of the roughness of the surface of the Cylinder), you'll actually get different bounces - look at Rutherford experiment, a flat surface starts acting far from like a surface.

Consider also light hitting glossy or matte objects, for when the smoothness is large or small relative to the interacting surface.

Imagine you zoom in at the point of the collision. If you zoom in enough, you will not see a curved surface, but rather a plane oriented in the same direction as the tangent to the circumference at that point. Same as we on earth do not perceive the earth's curvature.
When you see it that way, it makes no sense for the particle to bounce back (unless it is moving towards the center). It is similar as a collision with the floor when the particle is colliding at an angle, it will bounce back with the same (but opposite direction) angle relative to the vertical if momentum and energy are conserved.
